# Spring Security, REST Api и DataSource

Tags: java, spring, curl, jdbc, spring-security

пишу REST Api сервер, хочу добавить авторизацию. Для теста добавил следующие ресурсы

1. `GET /api/test/getting`, который возвращает `privet` всем без авторизации
2. `GET /api/test/secret`, который возвращает `SECREEEET` только авторизованым пользователем.

Сейчас Spring Security настраивается следующим образом:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?")
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/getting").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling();
    }
```

Через браузер и curl, первый ресурс выдает всем `privet`. А при попытке обратится ко второму через браузер перекидывает на форму логина, а потом отправляет `POST /login` с параметрами `username=XXX&password=XXX&submit=Login`, после чего в запросы добавляются куки. Я попробовал повторить такое поведение через curl с сохранением куки в файл, но меня сразу выкидывает с ошибкой 403.

Хочу узнать, как явно задать настройки логина, задание куков и убрать эту перессылку на логин, чтобы кидало ошибку 401.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда пришлось решать все самим, напишу сам ответ, вдруг кому пригодится.

Решилась эта проблема на самом деле очень просто, необходимо было реализовать свой `authenticationEntryPoint`.

Итоговый код конфигурационного класса наследуемого от `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/getting").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
}
```

И вот сам код `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, который наследуется от `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

```
@Override
public void commence
        (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
        throws IOException {
    response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm='" + getRealmName() + "'");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authEx.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setRealmName("Watch Counter");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

В итоге открыт доступ без авторизации к `/api/test/getting`, но ко всему остальному нужна авторизация и без нее возвращается ошибка 401 с сообщением `HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource`.

Answer (score 0):

Отлуп неавторизованных запросов с кодом ошибки в xml-конфигурации делается так

```
<beans:bean id="authEntryPoint"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg name="httpStatus" 
                     value="#{T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).UNAUTHORIZED}" />
</beans:bean>

<security:http use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/test/getting" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/.*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

Правда, я бы лучше использовал [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.html).

И для API лучше подойдёт аутентификация не через форму и куки, а передачей в заголовках jwt-токена или basic-credentials.

Comment: 403 обычно используют, когда ты авторизован, но не хватает прав доступа, поэтому и пишется 403 Forbidden («запрещено (не уполномочен)»). Логичнее на неавторизованные запросы отвечать ошибкой 401 Unauthorized («не авторизован (не представился)»).

Comment: Вот только надо отличать одних от других, а стандартные эндпоинты этого не умеют. Надо либо писать свой, наследуясь от [AuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html), либо полностью переезжать на иной механизм аутентификации.