# Настройка Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Я хочу сделать следующее приложение:
Есть 2 конечные токи API:
1) /hello/user - возвращает строку Hello ${username}, где username имя пользователя
2) /hello/anonymous - возвращает не авторизованному пользователю строку Hello world

Я испробовал множество вариантов настройки из примеров которые мне выдал google, но настроить то что я хотел не получилось.
Даже если в API для  `/hello/anonymous` я указывал настройках безопасности: `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello/anonymous").permitAll()`
мне всеравно показывалось сообщение
`Full authentication is required to access this resource`, такое чувство что API не обращается к серверу авторизации или на сервере авторизации что то настроено не правильно.

Возможно кто то сможет мне помочь с настройкой OAuth2.
Если нужно могу выложить то что я смог сделать.

Comment: Да, надо код выложить. Весь)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб залил код на https://github.com/Bleser92/welcome

Comment: Я работаю примерно над тем же и уперся в такую же проблему
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845675/spring-security-rest-api-%D0%B8-datasource
Вдруг мой код из вопроса чем-то может помочь

Comment: @TiiRiiX У меня данная ошибка пропала, но появилась другая проблема. Я создал новый вопрос возможно это чем то вам поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846047/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-spring-oauth2