# Бесконечный редирект при использовании Spring Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Я настраиваю OAuth2 через  spring boot 2, но после ввода логина и пароля меня постоянно перекидывает на форму входа. В http клиенте я проследил чепочку, но ошибки которая бы говорила о том что пароль не верный не увидел.

1)http://localhost:4002/hello/user [GET]
2)http://localhost:4002/login [GET]
3)http://localhost:5000/oauth/authorize?client_id=browser&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4002/login&response_type=code&state=jRLNqa [GET]
4)http://localhost:5000/login [GET]
5)http://localhost:5000/login [POST] form username=bleser;password=123
6)http://localhost:5000/oauth/authorize?client_id=browser&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4002/login&response_type=code&state=c7jCbQ [GET]
7) http://localhost:4002/login?code=GnffIl&state=c7jCbQ
8) пункт 2

[Пример кода](https://github.com/Bleser92/welcome)

Comment: В твоём случае скорее полностью закрыта страница `/login`, хотя она должна быть открыта для случае, когда клиент приходит с OAuth-сервера с кодом (параметр `code`)

Comment: @Темкатоже Spring Boot задумывался для облегчения настройки проекта, но сейчас мне он кажется просто адом конфигов которые конфликтуют друг с другом.Мне кажется лучше писать все самому, пусть это будет дольше, но зато полный контроль над происходящим.